# How to determine type of a dependency property that requests value in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I get dependency property type that requests value in XAML, and this dependency property binded to property of type Object in code-behind.
For example I have in XAML

```
...
<TextBox Width={Binding prop} Text={Binding prop}>
...
```

in code:

```
public object prop
{
  get
   {

      if (isInt)      //need to determine XAML property type 
        return 100;
      else
        return "someText";
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The returned property value should not depend on the target type of a binding. Instead, you might add a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) to perform conversions for certain binding target types.

Comment: Or you just have different properties for the various bindings. That's what view models are made for.

Comment: If you just think about it for a minute, I hope that you'd realise that this is a terrible idea.

Comment: I want to use it for saving window size and some other data from UI that may be customized by user. I use for it indexed properties that allow resolving properties at runtime accessing them from XAML by string.